# Moving spring annotation to common package

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, spring-aop

I have an annotation named `@UserHasAccess` which is used to check user's access based on some service call. In the advice, I have some dependency to call the service. This is the advice class:

```
public class UserHasAccessAdvice{

    @Autowired
    ServiceClient client;

    //Other methods
}
```

Now I am planning to move this annotation to a common project so that I can use it in all the projects. When I tried, I am getting compilation error as `ServiceClient` is not present in the common project. How can I reuse this annotation by moving it to a common package? How to inject the service class based on the target project?

I am using Spring Boot 2.x

Comment: Make `ServiceClient` an interface in the common project, with implementations in the various projects which will use it as a dependency.  Or, if `ServiceClient` is also re-usable then move `ServiceClient` to the common project as well.

Comment: You said you want to "move this annotation to a common project". Where is the problem? The annotation does not have any auto-wired service client, only the advice class does. So maybe clarify your question. Do you in reality want to move the advice class to a common project instead of the annotation? Or maybe both? If you move the annotation but not the advice there should not be any problem.

Comment: @kriegaex I want to move both annotation and advice class.

Comment: @AndrewS I will try that approach by creating an interface.

Comment: Maybe you want to reconsider that design decision. In order to keep authorisation as much as possible an independent cross-cutting concern, I would just move the annotation to a common package and not the aspect or advice implementing it. That way you can easily run the application without authorisation for tests, replace the Spring AOP by an AspectJ, Spring Security or annotation processing solution etc. IMO you shouldn't design your application so as to fail if you remove the aspect. A good aspect does its job when present but does not break the application when not present.

Comment: @kriegaex Thank you for your reply. I will reconsider my design.